# Detecting 2 Android Devices Touching/Bumping

Tags: android, sensors, detect, android-sensors, bump

I have a feature in my app that requires the detection of when two devices touch and im wondering what the best way to go about figuring out when this happens is? and is there a way to detect such a event even when my app is running in the background?

Comment: This could be of help: http://bu.mp/company/api

Comment: Since the Bump API is going away, I have been looking at the android standard Sensor.TYPE_LINEAR_ACCELERATION. ChuckKelly, did you ever find something that works for you (I have the same need)?